# Dismiss a custom UIView like the way in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uiview, uipopovercontroller

Im building a custom UIView similar to UIPopover view , simply I subclass the UIView class and build the stuff of controls and events inside .. to show this view I assign the superView through My sub Class datasource like this

```
    if ([dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(containerView)]) 
        superView = [dataSource containerView];
```

and to show it I have a function doing that like this

```
- (void) showPopOverFromRect : (CGRect) rect
{
    CGSize popSize = self.frame.size;

    float yPoint;

    if(ntPopOverDirection == NTPopOverArrowDirectionUP)
        yPoint = rect.origin.y + 10;
    else
        yPoint = rect.origin.y - 10;

    self.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x - popSize.width, yPoint , popSize.width, popSize.height);

    [superView addSubview:self];
}
```

so My Question .. how can i dismiss this view (remove it) if the user tap AnyWhere on the superView just like the UIPopOverController ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could place a UIButton below your new UIView that is clear.  When this new button is pressed, it dismisses your view and removes itself from superview.

Something like:

```
- (void) showPopOverFromRect : (CGRect) rect
{
    CGSize popSize = self.frame.size;

    float yPoint;

    if(ntPopOverDirection == NTPopOverArrowDirectionUP)
        yPoint = rect.origin.y + 10;
    else
        yPoint = rect.origin.y - 10;

    self.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x - popSize.width, yPoint , popSize.width, popSize.height);

    UIButton *dismissButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    dismissButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dismissButton.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [dismissButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(dismissPopover) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [superview addSubview:dismissButton];

    [superView addSubview:self];
}
```

You'd have to set up the view to set it's superview as a delegate that receives the message to dismiss the popover, though.

Comment: oh how i missed that ! with some modification it works .. thanks.

Comment: What if the user taps to the left or right or above the popover?  They will not tap the "clear" button.

Comment: @bbarnhart but in UIPopController if you tap anywhere except the popover and beside its arrow it will be dismissed ! so whats the wrong with that ?

Comment: In @Jacob comment, I took "below" to mean in the Y coordinate of the custom view and not in the Z coordinate.  But, in the code I see the button fills the entire screen.  However, using a UIButton instead of UITapGestureRecognizer seems sloppy.

Comment: @bbarnhart, any particular reason why? For me, it's a relic of the days before UITapGestureRecognizers (iPhoneOS 2.0) but really doesn't have any serious ramifications as to why it would it would be "worse" than your solution. If anything, you can color the button for the sake of debugging to make sure that there aren't any issues with tap coordinates overlapping or conflicting. Also, what if the superview you're putting a UITapGestureRecognizer on doesn't fill the entire screen but is within Navigation Controller?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you create your custom UIView to fill the entire superview or the entire screen with a clear background or a radial gradient.  Then inside of this you would put another UIView that has the look and feel of the popover.

This eliminates the issue of trying to capture taps and sending notifications from other views.  It will be all self contained.

You can easily add a gesture recognizer inside your custom view to close the view when the user touches the clear area.